# Subtracting 2 pointers with a signed result, appropriate for input to a red-black-tree "comparator"

Tags: c, pointers

In C does the following work?

```
struct fdBase *left, *right;
int result = (int)(left - right);
```

`result` can be negative. If that doesn't work, how do I write it?

My goal is to have something to provide to my red-black-tree sort function, a so called "comparator" for pointers. **I am not doing array work**, I need the actual difference between the pointers, in bytes.

Comment: Thought this would be helpful: *When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
subscripts of the two array elements.* - C11 §6.5.6/9

Comment: You realize that it's not a difference in bytes but a difference in `struct fdBase` size units, right?

Comment: Pointer subtraction is used as a very fast way to determine the number of elements between two elements in an array. Of course if the first element is to the right of the second element, you get a negative result.

Comment: @BenJackson No I did not, how do I get a difference in bytes?

Answer (score 7):

The result of subtraction of two pointers in C has a signed result, by definition. The result has `ptrdiff_t` type, which is a signed integral type.

The important detail here is that you are not allowed to subtract just two arbitrary pointers. In order for the result to be defined, the pointers have to point to elements of the same array (or to the imaginary "one past the end" element).

The result of the subtraction is expressed in elements, not in bytes, i.e. it works consistently with the rest of pointer arithmetic in C. The result of `A - B` can and will be be negative, if `A` points to an element with greater index than `B`.

If you need the difference in bytes between the raw addresses the pointers are pointing to, the more-or-less formally valid way to do it would be the following

```
intptr_t difference = (intptr_t) left - (intptr_t) right;
```

That way you are not subtracting pointers (since it is not defined for arbitrary pointers), but rather subtracting their integer representations. The result of `(intptr_t) some_pointer` conversion is implementation-defined, but typically it is the physical memory address stored in the pointer. This method, unfortunately, has some problems of its own: it might produce incorrect results for pointers that have `1` is the high-order bits. Such pointers will normally produce negative values when converted to `intptr_t`.

Comment: This is not what I wanted. Updating my question.

Comment: @dongle26 if you want to compare two pointers for equality then use `==` operator.

Comment: @ouah The library I am using wants the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
struct fdBase *left, *right;
void *result = (void *)left - (void *)right;
```

Two other ideas:

1 - Assuming that the function you are using require that your comparator should return a negative number if (left < right), 0 if (left = right) and a positive number if (left > right):

```
    struct fdBase *left, *right;
    if (left < right)
        return -1;
    else if (left == right)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
```

Or a more compact version:

```
    if (left < right) ? -1 : (if (left == right) ? 0 : 1)
```

2 - Multiply the difference of your subtraction by `sizeof(fdBase)`:

```
    struct fdBase *left, *right;
    int result = (int)(left - right) * sizeof(fdBase)
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is not allowed in C with `void *`.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong, but it works with gcc 4.6.1. Maybe it is an unorthodox feature.

Comment: Just because it works on most architectures, it's not guaranteed to work in the cross-platform sense of C standard.

Comment: @kikou try to add `-pedantic` to your `gcc` options and you'll get the desired diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers so far, I think what I want is:

```
struct fdBase *left, *right;
ptrdiff_t result = (char *)left - (char *)right;
```

Comment: The result of the subtraction of two pointers is an integer not a pointer.

Comment: This is correct but, as @AndreyT mentioned, as long as `*left` and `*right` are elements of the same `struct fdBase` array.  (And also assuming the distance fits in an `int`, as pointer difference is of type `ptrdiff_t`.)